# Handling soap and wsdl webservice in node.js

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I want to handle a soap and wsdl service from node.js,for the initial startup i downloaded the node-soap module and ran the example js file it asked me to download modules like 
node-expat after that it gave me the following error

```
> Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/node_expat.node'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\290495\Desktop\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\no
de-expat\lib\node-expat.js:4:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
```

any idea as how to handle the above issues will be really helpful!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dependencies for the soap module didn't get installed properly. Did you run "npm install soap" from your node root directory?

Answer (score 0):

looks like an install issue,

i see you are on windows, - node_expat compiles some binary plugin I have noticed in their project folder a .cc ... i have seen other packages do this, under mac/linux if you have compiler tools installed it simply compiles the plugins and installs fine.

under windows i think it will be a little more convoluted, you could try installing the following:

Windows XP/Vista/7:
Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 (Express version works well)
For 64-bit builds of node and native modules you will also need the Windows 7 64-bit SDK
If you get errors that the 64-bit compilers are not installed you may also need the compiler update for the Windows SDK 7.1

Windows 8:
Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012 for Windows Desktop (Express version works well)

I think with the express version npm will pick up your dev toolchain as msvc and compile up the node_expat extension....

Comment: alternatively you will need to install a gcc toolchain for windows and add it to your windows environment options